# wrong format for time data pandas

Tags: pandas, strptime

what is the correct date format for the time
`2020-02-24T18:00:00`
I have tried using  `dates_cc = dt.datetime.strptime(dates_c, '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')`
but I get a wrong date format error.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a `T` should work:

```
import datetime as dt
dates_c = "2020-02-24T18:00:00"
dates_cc = dt.datetime.strptime(dates_c, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
dates_cc
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 24, 18, 0)
```